# Are there publicly available fast Laplacian solvers?

Tags: linear-algebra

In a much celebrated result, we know that there is a $ O(m\log \frac{1}{\epsilon}) $ time algorithm for solving laplacian systems of the form $Lx=b$ where $L$ is a laplacian of a graph $G$ with $m$ edges to within $\epsilon$ accuracy (skipping some of the technical details).

As far as I know, the algorithm is quite involved, and not really practical to implement. I am curious if there are known fast practical algorithms that can solve such systems to close the gap between theory and practice? Obviously, you can feed the
Laplacian to a linear system solver, but I wonder if some solvers can exploit the Laplacian nature to speed up the computation.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, Daniel Spielman (one of the authors of said result) maintains [a page](https://sites.google.com/a/yale.edu/laplacian/) regarding the topic. It has a “code” section:

> If you need to solve diagonally-dominant linear systems, I also suggest trying the Algebraic Multigrid algorithm. You can find an implementation in the LAMG package, written by Oren Livne.

The [library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lamg/) seems to be written in Matlab (yuck),  but seems specifically tailored for the purpose. I’ll give it a try and report how well it does in a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't Finite Element Methods or Vector-Fitting or Fast-Multi-pole-Method   a kind of solution for laplacian equations?  They are implemented well in many programming languages.